# How to find ID from an answer on askubuntu

Tags: support, answers

I would like to know how to find the post ID of an answer on **askubuntu.com**.

An example:

I want to get the post ID of [l0b0's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/167400/) on [How can I change my own user ID?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16700/). I need it because I want to ask a question and link the answer by **l0b0**.

I to do how **mook765** to say,

> you'll find the user-id in the searchbar in the top

The user-id of **l0b0** is **10371** but when I go to `https://askubuntu.com/questions/16700/how-can-i-change-my-own-user-id/10371`,  I land on the top of the answers instead of l0b0's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `share` button below every post to easily get a direct link to a specific answer or question:

[image: "share a link to this answer" button]

This link is of the format `https://askubuntu.com/TYPE/POST_ID/USER_ID`, where

- `TYPE` is the type of the post, i.e. `q` for questions or `a` for answers,
- `POST_ID` (highlighted in the screenshot above) is, well, the ID number of this specific post, and
- `USER_ID` is your own user ID, so that any clicks on this link can be tracked back to you. (There are e.g. some badges for sharing links that get clicked by a number of unique IP addresses). This part is optional and you could also remove it if you want an anonymous link.

You can either just use this short direct link, or if you prefer the long link format that includes the question title slug plus an anchor to the desired answer, you can also use the post ID you retrieved from the `share` link and append that (both as path component as well as anchor), like

https://askubuntu.com/questions/16700/how-can-i-change-my-own-user-id/167400#167400